# Redux state not updating right away?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

setCurrentPage just stores the object into a page object in my global store.  so if i try to access it RIGHT after i set it.. it seems like there's a delay and the object is empty.  but if i console.log the same object in a button after and click it.. it's populated.

is there a lag in redux that I dont know about?  what can I do to get this to work?  it's messing up my code...

thanks for any help

```
// initialState.js // my global redux store
playlist: {
  currentPage: {}
}

// someComponent
let tempPage = new Page();
tempPage.controlNode = someAPItoGetControlNode();  //synchronous
this.props.actions.setCurrentPage(tempPage);  //tempPage.controlNode contains object correctly
console.log(this.props.currentPage);  //empty object.  WHY???

// in some function in the same component i call in a button
function seeCurrentPage() {
  console.log(this.props.currentPage);  //works!  
}

// reducer
case types.SET_CURRENT_PAGE: {
  action.pageObj.selected = true;
  return Object.assign({}, state, {currentPage: action.pageObj});
}

// action
export function setCurrentPage(pageObj) {
  return { type: types.SET_CURRENT_PAGE, pageObj: pageObj };
}
```

Comment: Redux store updates synchronously, but your component doesn't

Comment: @AlexeyTen so each line of code in my component doesn't wait for the line before it?  can you verify if that's what you mean?  how can I get this to work then?

Comment: It waits. But store and props are not directly connected, so changes in store does not immediately propagate to props

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for a delayed information is not because of redux, but because of the asynchronous execution of your `component`.

```
// someComponent
let tempPage = new Page();
tempPage.controlNode = someAPItoGetControlNode();  //synchronous
this.props.actions.setCurrentPage(tempPage);  //tempPage.controlNode contains object correctly
console.log(this.props.currentPage);
```

In the above code, your component fires an action and then immediately after logs `this.props.currentPage`. However by that time the redux store would not have updated and hence you get an older result

What you can do is log in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     console.log(nextProps.currentPage)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After the Redux store is updated, your component will need to re-render.

So you can just write the `console.log` in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` or `componentDidUpdate()`, then you can access to the new data from the store.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this also.  It is an asynchronous issue when updating props like everyone is saying.  I solved it by using async await.  If you want to get the updated props immediately then you can do something like:

```
    async function myFunction () {
      await this.props.actions.setCurrentPage(tempPage);
      console.log(this.props.currentPage); // shows updated props
    }
```

In this code the console log waits for the async operation to complete then gets your props.

Comment: This didn't work. as the normal reducer isn't async