# Why I can't change the state in my redux function?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm learning redux and I made a simple reducer which decreaces or increaces the number. It looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
    index: 0,
}

interface Action{
    type: string;
}
function firstReducer(state = initialState, action: Action) {
    // Reducers usually look at the type of action that happened
    // to decide how to update the state
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'counter/incremented':
        return { ...state, index: state.index + 1 }
      case 'counter/decremented':
        return { ...state, index: state.index - 1 }
      default:
        // If the reducer doesn't care about this action type,
        // return the existing state unchanged
        return state
    }
  }

export default firstReducer;
```

I copied it from official docs. My store:

```
export const store = createStore(firstReducer);
```

And how I implement it in a component:

```
const state = store.getState();   //getting state from store and using dispatch
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const prevSlide = () =>{    //function to decrease the number
    dispatch({type: 'counter/decremented'});
    console.log(state.index);
  }

const nextSlide = () =>{   //function to increase the numbers
    dispatch({type:'counter/incremented'});
    console.log(state.index);
  }
```

The buttons:

```
<BsArrowLeft className="arrow left" onClick={() => prevSlide()}/>
<BsArrowRight className="arrow right" onClick={() => nextSlide()}/>
```

So with all this the console displays `0` everytime I click on a button. I'm not sure what can be problem, cause it's a pretty simple function.

Edit:
I assigned `state.index` to a key in the div, so everytime I click one of the buttons, the state should change and therefore the divs should change, getting an active class, like this:

```
<div 
            className={`poster__item ${state.index===key ? 'active' : ''}`}
            key={key}
            >
```

I console logged to see if the state changes and it didn't someone in the comments said the state changes, but console doesn't change it. But even when I click on the button to change a div class, still nothing happens.

Comment: The state is almost certainly updating as expected, the problem is with trying to console log during the same render and expecting it to be changed already. State updates (redux or otherwise) cannot be observed during the same render that triggers the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redux state not updating right away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778511/redux-state-not-updating-right-away)

Comment: @BrianThompson hi! i edited my question. i also assigned `state.index` to key value in div so div class changes everytime i click on the button, but still nothing happens

Comment: Where are you using `store.getState()`? You should probably be using `useSelector` to get the state instead. I believe the logic that causes re-renders of a component is located in this hook, whereas calling `getState` directly does not have a way to inform React that the component should re-render