# Redux Array returns empty data on first button click

Tags: reactjs

I am storing object data in my redux state with the `saveToRedux` Function

```
const saveToRedux = () => {
    const data = {id: 1, name: 'Kelly'};
   dispatch(saveData(data));
}
```

onClick of the button below I am calling saveToRedux Function as well as trying to get the savedData from the state. But after clicking the button for the first time, it returns an empty array, except I click it for the second time before it returns the savedData.

```
  <button onClick={() => getData()}>Click Me</button>

  const { savedData } = useSelector((state) => state.data);


const getData = () => {
   saveToRedux();
  console.log('Saved Redux Data: ', savedData); //returns empty array on first click
}
```

Comment: Checkout [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [Redux state not updating right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778511/redux-state-not-updating-right-away)

Answer (score 0):

```
const getData = React.useCallback(() => {
   saveToRedux();
   console.log('Saved Redux Data: ', savedData);
}, [savedData])
```

`getData` function don't know data is updated yet. So by using `useCallback` and setting dependency with `savedData`, you can see updated data.